# Load an XML and add a node to it

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

What I am trying to do is when I press a button, I load an XML file and try to add nodes to it.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("XMLFILE.xml"); 
XmlNode Tag1 = doc.CreateElement("Tag1");
XmlNode Tag2 = doc.CreateElement("Tag2");
Tag2.InnerText = food.Text;
Tag1.AppendChild(Tag2);

XmlNode Tag3 = doc.CreateElement("Tag3");
Tag3.InnerText = games.Text;
Tag1.AppendChild(Tag3);

XmlNode Tag4 = doc.CreateElement("Tag4");
Tag4.InnerText = life.Text;
Tag1.AppendChild(Tag4);
```

When I run the code and click the button the file is empty and only has 1 tag which is one I made when I first created the file. So how can I load an XML and add to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with the code you posted:

1. You created a bunch of XML nodes but I don't see anywhere that you actually add them to the document you loaded. You need to call `AppendChild()` on the `DocumentElement` or some other node that's already in the file if you want your new nodes to appear in the XML tree.
2. Your code is loading an XML document from disk into memory and editing it, but you are never storing the XML document back to disk again. You need to call [`Save()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save.aspx) on the updated document if you want to see the changes persisted back to your file.